# How to reconnect the Dealer in Zeromq

Tags: zeromq, router, reconnect

I'm using the pattern: **Router-Dealer**

**Router** send messages to **Dealer(A)** all the time.

**Dealer** just receive message (SOCKOPT_IDENTITY: A).

Work fine in this time.

Then 
i press **Ctrl-C** to stop the **Dealer** , and reconnect.
Now i got nothing ~~

Is there anything wrong?
How can i fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong kind of sockets and/or direction of messages.
I would be easier to understand what you would like to do if you write what you are using the socket for.
Assuming that you want to use Dealer and Router sockets then you should send the message in the other direction (Dealer => Router).

The Router socket connects many inputs to a single output or a single input to many outputs. This is done by adding/removing an identifier to the message, that describes where it came from or where it should go.

So in your case when you are trying to send a message from the router, the router socket will try to remove the identifier from the message, so that it can understand which connection it should forward the message on. So if you really want this then you need to associate your dealer connection with an identifier and then add that to the message that your sending through the router.
But I'm pretty sure that you actually want to use another combination of zmq sockets.

Comment: Rather, I want to send a message to the specified user.

Comment: And I dropped the issue must be resolved.
Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Thank you,sammygadd . I found the answer. [github](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/79)